# Filling a datgrid from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

```
        DataTable Titles = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AssessmentData.GetConnection());
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlGetTitles = new SqlCommand("[HRO_AAT].[dbo].[GetPositionLibrary]", connection);
        sqlGetTitles.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlTitles = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGetTitles);
        sqlTitles.Fill(Titles);

        connection.Close();

        gvPositions.DataSource = Titles.DefaultView;
```

I am using the above code to populate a datagrid in ASP.NET based on the user's selection from a drop-down list and a stored procedure in a Sql Server database.  It appears to be running properly because I put a breakpoint in the function and it went through each line without error but it is not displaying the datagrid and the stored procedure is returning data.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Show whole function. Looks like your DataTable object is local, and after function completes it is destroy by GC collector.

Comment: There are plenty of samples out there. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/example-of-datagrid-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Try binding DataSource to Titles, not Titles.DefaultView

Comment: The DataTable is local but the gridview isn't.  I have tried both woth the DefaultView and without it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered wrapping your code in a method that returns a DataTable?

For example:

```
    public DataTable Get_Stored_Procedure_Data()
    {
        DataTable Titles = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AssessmentData.GetConnection());
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlGetTitles = new SqlCommand("[HRO_AAT].[dbo].[GetPositionLibrary]", connection);
            sqlGetTitles.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter sqlTitles = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGetTitles);
            sqlTitles.Fill(Titles);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return Titles;
    }
```

Then:

```
     DataTable results = Get_Stored_Procedure_Data();
     gvPositions.DataSource = Titles.DefaultView;
```

Also, I've add a try, catch, finally as good practice.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to have the user select a title form a drop-down list and then populate the gridview based on that selection.  This function is in the drop-down OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: Create a public datatable, public_dt, in your Form and bind it to your DGV immediately. Inside the event, OnSelectedIndexChanged, call the method I created above and set it equal to the public datatable, public_dt.